# Setting up multiple sites in WAMP

Tags: wamp

I've previously had a Drupal installation set up in WAMP. It's still in my www folder.

I want to start work on another (Wordpress) site. I made a new folder in WAMP and set the Drupal folder to Drupal.old so that it wouldn't use it, but I could still keep it there.

Now when I go to PHP My Admin in WAMP it just displays a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong? I just need to install WP on my local machine

Comment: Try these Instructions It might Helps You :

http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/creating-multiple-virtual-websites-in-wampserver/

Answer (score 0):

Francesca,

You should never put anything of yours in the www folder. That belongs to WAMP and is basically the localhost site. So by renaming it you have deleted the loclahost site and therefore phpmyadmin with is an alias off your now lost localhost site.

You should either create subfolder below the www folder for your sites like

```
c:\wamp\www\drupal1
c:\wamp\www\wordpress1
```

But that is not the best solution.
It is better to create Vistual Hosts, one virtual host for each of your sites.

Pop over to the [WAMPSERVER Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2)

Do a search on 'Vistual Host HOWTO' and you should find a tutorial on how they are setup.

Comment: Oh, ok i must have misunderstood. Does localhost still show the WAMP hoempage?